# Java GZIP file corrupted when using newline character

Tags: java

The following code only works when I remove the append("\n"):

```
  StringBuilder dataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  dataBuilder.append("id,name,class,test");
  dataBuilder.append("\n"); // new line <-- this corrupts the gzip file
  dataBuilder.append(String.join(",", dataArray)); // add actual data

  String data = dataBuilder.toString();
  byte[] bytes = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Passed to subsequent function that converts to GZIP and sends to remote service.

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  GZIPOutputStream gzipOut = new GZIPOutputStream(byteOut);

  gzipOut.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
  gzipOut.finish();
  ...
```

I'm trying to create a delimited file and send it to a remote storage service, in GZIP format.

When I append the newline character, the GZIP file can't be opened. (I download and try and open on a Mac, and it fails to open). Removing the newline character everything works as expected, but it's all on one line.

System.lineSeparator() makes no difference.

There are certain combinations that do work:

```
  dataBuilder.append("\n"); // new line at beginning of file
  dataBuilder.append(headerRow);
  dataBuilder.append(String.join(",", dataArray)); // data
```

This doesn't work:

```
  dataBuilder.append("\n"); // new line at beginning
  dataBuilder.append(headerRow);
  dataBuilder.append("\n"); // new line after header
  dataBuilder.append(String.join(",", dataArray)); // data
```

It also makes no difference if I place the \n within the same append() call, or using a subsequent append.

Comment: Ok, so if I download to Windows, there is no problem. Still using "\n".

Comment: It might corrupt the unzipped data, but it can't possibly corrupt the GZIP file.

Comment: Using gunzip from the command line on MacOS works. So I guess this is not really a programming related problem afterall... not my problem anyway. Should I delete the question?